# How to show bootstrap popover for invalid input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-popover

I've some input boxes where if it's value is other than 1,I need to show a popover saying it is invalid for that particular input.

**My code**

```
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" class="check" />
<input type="text" class="check" />
<input type="text" class="check" />
<input type="text" class="check" />
<input type="button" id="Save" value="Save" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Save").click(function() {
    $(".check").each(function() {
      $val = $(this).val();
      if ($val != 1) {      
        $(this).popover({
          content: "Invalid"
        });
      }
    })
  })
})
```

<kbd>[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/bqo5mdcz/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing the `.popover` plugin, but you are not telling it to `show`.

Just do this:

`$(this).popover('show');`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bqo5mdcz/3/

Comment: Also could you please tell how to dismiss that ?

Comment: @Hazard Check out the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You miss just this one thing, a call to the popover show function :

```
$(this).popover({
          content: "Invalid"
}).popover("show");
```

If you want to remove the popovers, then call the destroy function :

```
$(".popover:visible").popover( "destroy" );
```

It will destroy all the visible popovers at once.